# unable to install google cloud sdk on windows 10

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install google cloud sdk on my windows 10 machine.
the installer stops at below error. there is no way i dont have the permission on the directory as i just created the directory for the sdk.

```
Output folder: C:\dev\gcloud
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\dev\gcloud\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Your current Cloud SDK version is: 207.0.0
Installing components from version: 207.0.0

ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Access is denied: [C:\dev\gcloud\google-cloud-sdk.staging\.install\.backup]
Ensure you have the permissions to access the file and that the file is not in use.
This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.
Failed to install.
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would recommend you to check and make sure you are running the install as administrator as you have receiving a “Access is denied” error.

Running a program 'as Administrator' (as in on the right-click menu) and doing a RunAs Administrator are not the same thing:

Running a program 'as Administrator' means that the program still runs under the context of your user account (i.e. the person invoking the program) but using a modified access token that includes membership of the Administrators group. A process started in this way would show as being owned by you in Task Manager.

Using RunAs with the Administrator account really does try to invoke the program under the Administrator account. A process started in this way would show as being owned by Administrator in the Task Manager.

Additionally, you can follow [this article](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-run-programs-administrator-windows-7) more specifically “1. Run a program as administrator from the Start Menu (in Windows 10 and Windows 7) or Start Screen (in Windows 8.1)” point which will help you to run programs as administrator in Windows 10.